# Usinge ternary operators within tables Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wanting to display some amounts based on if one intrest amount is higher than the other, here is the logic:

```
<td *ngIf="subTable.flexitaxMaxPaymentDate">
                subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest > subTable.IRDInterest ? {{subTable.maxAmountWithTmnzInterest | formatNegativeNumber}} ({{subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest | formatNegativeNumber}}) : ''
              </td>
```

So in this logic, if `flexitaxMaxInterest` is greater than `IRDInterest`, I want to show the following within the `<td>` : `{{subTable.maxAmountWithTmnzInterest | formatNegativeNumber}} ({{subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest | formatNegativeNumber}})` , if this boolean turns out false I want to show an empty string.

My issue is that when the table renders I get the following output:

```
subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest > subTable.IRDInterest ? $926 ($26) : ''
```

within the table which is not what I want, I have played about with it but haven't managed to get anywhere. What would be the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case: don't show anything if condition, you can use a `<ng-container>` see [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

```
<td *ngIf="subTable.flexitaxMaxPaymentDate">
   <ng-container *ngIf="subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest > subTable.IRDInterest">
      {{subTable.maxAmountWithTmnzInterest | formatNegativeNumber}}
      ({{subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest | formatNegativeNumber}})
   </ng-container>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `Math.max` function to your component :

```
getMax = Math.max;
```

Now you can use

```
<td>
  {{ getMax(subTable.flexitaxMaxInterest, subTable.IRDInterest) | formatNegativeNumber }}
</td>
```

Comment: By the way, your error was forgetting interpolation `{{  }}`